# How to animate background image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Hi I'm trying to animate a background image using jQuery, I tried following [this tutorial here](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations), however I've had no luck with my test page, I see the blue Facebook icon, but on mouse over it does not animate upwards to reveal the gray logo. Please help! Thanks, I'm a jQuery noob.

**My test page:**
http://leongaban.com/_stack/bg_animation/

The Facebook icon should animation upwards, the full image below:

[image]

*My CSS*

```
<style>
    #facebook_icon li {
        padding: 0;
        width: 120px;
        height: 119px;
        list-style: none;
        background: red;
        background:url('img/fb_120x238.png') repeat 0 0;
    }
</style>
```

*HTML*

```
<ul id="facebook_icon">
    <li><a href="#"><div class="box"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

*Javascript*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bgpos.js"></script>

<script>

    (function() {
        $('#facebook_icon li')
            .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
            .mouseover(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate(
                    {backgroundPosition:"(0 -119px)"},
                    {duration:500})
                })
            .mouseout(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate(
                    {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
                    {duration:500})
                })
    })();

</script>
```

**UPDATE: WORKING CSS 3 Solution**

*CSS 3*

```
#facebook_icon li {
        padding: 0;
        width: 120px;
        height: 119px;
        list-style: none;
        background: red;
        background:url('img/fb_120x238.png') repeat 0 0;

        -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
        -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
        -o-transition: background-position 1s;
        transition: background-position 1s;
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    #facebook_icon li:hover{
        background-position: 0 -119px;
    }

    .box {
        width: 120px;
        height: 119px;
    }
```

*HTML* (Added empty div box to have something to click on)

```
<ul id="facebook_icon">
    <li><a href="#"><div class="box"></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can also use CSS3 transition.

Comment: why is your li in your a? Turn it the other way around.

Comment: You have an `li` in your `anchor`.

Comment: have you tried mouseenter() and mouseleave() instead?

Comment: first of all, you don't need `{duration:500}`. You can just pass 500. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Just as an FYI, you can't animate background-position in jQuery without a plug-in. the animate method only can handle one value and background-position needs two values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution should be using the css3 transition.
You can do something like this:

In Your CSS

```
#facebook_icon li{
    -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
    -o-transition: background-position 1s;
    transition: background-position 1s;
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#facebook_icon li:hover{
     background-position: 0 -119px;
}
```

Comment: WOOT yeah this is so much simpler... I love CSS3 :) I've used it to animate opacity before... I guess I'll save jQuery for something a bit more complex

Answer (score 3):

This one is thankfully pretty simple. You are animating `background-position` on the anchor, but the actual image is on the li.

Just change your selector in your JavaScript:

```
 $('#facebook_icon li')
```

However, I'd recommend changing your markup (and accompanying CSS) so the `a` is inside the `li` instead of a child of the `ul`. That way your markup is valid.

**Update:**

Hey, so I totally agree with using CSS3. Its exactly how I would implement that. But just to close out the question: To get the `bgpos` plugin working with jQuery 1.8.2, change the first two lines of the `backgroundPosition` method to this:

```
 if (fx.start === 0 && typeof fx.end == 'string') {
    var start = $.css(fx.elem,'backgroundPosition');
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code and also included the jquery.bgpos.js the author was using... however still didn't work. Also I moved the A tag inside of the li and now I lose the hover state. I kinda don't want any text inside of the li, maybe I should put the image inside the li? Maybe the CSS 3 way would be better here

Comment: @Leon The author's plugin doesn't work with the latest jQuery. I dropped the version back to 1.4.2 and it started working

Comment: @Leon You can do one of two things with the hover state. Ideally, you give the `a` a width and height and display `block` or `inline-block` to keep the markup valid, but also get it working as you expect. The less nice alternative is just set `cursor: pointer` on the `li` in the CSS.

Comment: Ah thanks, forgot about the width and height for the a tag and display block!